# Windows 8 cmd cognos

Tags: windows, cmd

I have run into the following error trying to install Cognos on my windows 8 machine. What do I have to type into the console to make it work?

[image: Cognos Error]

Thx for the help!

Comment: You should ask on [su]

Answer (score 0):

Try this, assuming the switch is an i

```
"c:\path\installer.exe" -i console
```